# Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #17 while creating sunburst chart using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, sunburst-diagram, react-highcharts

[image]
[Document link for "data" i am using in chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sunburst)

I am using `ReactHighcharts` component for rendering the chart all other charts like line, bar, area, column all charts are working fine but when I tried with sunburst chart I am facing this error.

I am unable to identify the cause of this error. please let me know whats wrong i am doing.

```
   const sunburstconfig = {
        title: {
            text: 'World population 2017'
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            type: "sunburst",
            data: data,
            allowDrillToNode: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            }]

    };

    <ReactHighcharts config={sunburstconfig}></ReactHighcharts>
```

Comment: If you read https://www.highcharts.com/errors/17 it will tell you that *A typical reason may be that your are missing the extension file where the series type is defined, for example in order to run an arearange series you need to load the highcharts-more.js file.* So I would guess something is wrong with the way you import [sunburst.js](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sunburst.js), if you import it at all now.

Comment: In the index.html file i am using below 2 scripts this is only how, i am importing
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sunburst.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

Answer (score 3):

You need to import sunburst module in your react app:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock.src.js';
import sunburst from 'highcharts/modules/sunburst.js';
sunburst(Highcharts);
```

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/frameworks/react/192-use-highcharts-to-create-charts-in-react/